# Scripts And Styles Management Is Asp.net Mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm right now using asp.net mvc 4.5 in my projects . I like the way asp.net MVC is designed and works, but i am struggling with the script and styles sheet management.

Every page of my project use different style sheet and scripts files  so i can not add all the scripts and style sheet file in the layout file as it is not the good technique  & increase page loading time ,  i want to add  those related files on each page where they are needed. suggest me a good solution

Answer (score 1):

You could register a section in your layout:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

and then in each view override this section and define any custom scripts related to it:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/myscript.js")"></script>
}
```

Using this same technique you could define another section for the custom stylesheets.

This being said, if you take advantage of the built-in bundling and minification mechanism, it might be more effective to have a single minified and compressed file rather than multiple files because the browser will need to make separate HTTP request to retrieve them.

Comment: thanx please give me little description about  the working of @render section method also

Comment: Sure, you may checkout the following link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/12/15/razor-nested-layouts-and-redefined-sections.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend using ClientDipendancy Framework.

https://github.com/Shazwazza/ClientDependency